# Determining duplicate data based off of primary key input

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a SQL Server table A that is 1 to many with table B and C such that 1 entry in A can have many entries in B and C via foreign key.

I am passing the primary key of A into my stored procedure, from that I wish to determine if the input ABC relations has duplicate data to any ABC' relations in the database.

The condition of duplicate is as follows.

If the BC column data of the rows of the input also exist in the database for another A entry, we will call A`, then BC` is a duplicate of BC and A' is a duplicate of A. The procedure should return A' primary key.

So far I am stuck in determining how to do this in a declarative language. My latest attempt has a problem with the columns of B existing in C.

```
DECLARE @InputAPrimaryKey INT

SELECT B.APrimaryKey
FROM B, C
JOIN(SELECT *
     FROM  B, C
     WHERE B.APrimaryKey = C.APrimaryKey
     AND   B.AprimaryKey = @InputAPrimaryKey) As input
     ON input.Bcolumndata = B.columndata
     AND input.Ccolumndata = C.columndata
     AND ...
```

This results in red lines under 'As input' which stumps me.

Can anyone give advice on how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Well, what does the "red squiggly line" say when you hover over it?

Comment: Your alias "input" has doubles in column names . It is prohibited. Instead of * use explisit column names ( with alias ). ( Example - Your tables contain fields APrimaryKey )

Comment: @DimaSUN Is there a way around this without renaming all my column names? B and C have many column names which are exact.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab Your select part contains only B.APrimaryKey field, so You don't need many fields in parentheses

Comment: @DimaSUN Yes but I want to join on things other than B.APrimaryKey field. In my exmple I need to join on many things with AND so I can determine  BC = BC'. I cannot join on input unless I have all the columns that BC has as well.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab can you give  piece of data? And result you want ?

Comment: @marc_s I am confused I am not using * = * I am using a JOIN for the JOIN syntax.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab: you're using `SELECT * FROM  B, C` in your inner query - that's what I'm saying you should avoid

Answer (score 1):

Try smth like this one ( If I got right your task )

```
set nocount on

declare @A table ( APrimaryKey int not null )
insert @A values (1),(2),(3)

declare @B table ( APrimaryKey int not null, ColumnData nvarchar(10) )

insert @B values (1,'one'),(1,'four'),(3,'three'),(3,'four')

declare @C table ( APrimaryKey int not null, ColumnData nvarchar(10) )

insert @C values (1,'one'),(1,'two'),(2,'three'),(3,'two')

declare @Ainit integer = 1

select distinct B.APrimaryKey
from @B B
join @C C  on B.APrimaryKey = C.APrimaryKey
where exists  ( select B1.APrimaryKey
                from @B B1
                join @C C1
                on B1.APrimaryKey = C1.APrimaryKey
                and B1.APrimaryKey <> @Ainit

                and B1.ColumnData = B.ColumnData
                and C1.ColumnData = C.ColumnData
                -- Put your additional conditions
)
and  B.APrimaryKey <> @Ainit
```

Result is

```
APrimaryKey
-----------
     3
```